# resetting a global iterator to a list 

Tags: c++

```
#include<list>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

list<int> DL,TRS;
list<int>::iterator gitr;

void exchange();

int main() {
  DL.push_back(10);
  gitr=DL.begin();
  TRS.push_back(11);
  TRS.push_back(12);
  exchange();
  cout<<(*gitr)<<endl;
}

void exchange() {
  list<int> tdl;
  tdl=DL;
  DL.clear();
  DL=TRS;
  list<int>::iterator tmpitr=DL.begin();
  for(;tmpitr!=DL.end();++tmpitr)
     cout<<(*tmpitr)<<endl;
  DL.clear();
  DL=tdl;
}
```

This outputs 11 instead of 10. Why?

Comment: Why do you expect it to output 10?

Comment: There, I reformatted your code, but keep in mind that white space is your friend.

Comment: But you removed the question after the code.

Comment: @Etienne Fair point about the whitespace but since you’ve removed a crucial part of the question with your edit I’ve rolled back the changes. The formatting isn’t *that* important right now. A comment suffices.

Comment: @Konrad Yes, that was a rather stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2):

This program invokes undefined behavior, and is therefore allowed to do anything it wants - even printing 11 instead of 10.

Why is it UB? Because `gitr` is assigned `DL.begin()`, and then (inside the function `exchange`) `DL` is cleared, making `gitr` an invalid iterator. Dereferencing that iterator is UB.